# Creating tags/labels for daily builds

Tags: svn, version-control, tags, versioning

I am a release engineer and I just switched to a new company. As my role demands 
setting up the build process in the new company. We use svn for versioning here.

In my previous experience it has been a practice that every build will be 
accompanied with a tag. While defining the new process here, I tried to 
validate if this tag is really needed for every build.

Here are some of the pros and cons I can think of

Pros:

- Would help if we have to compare two builds
- There is no seperate need to tag different milestone build. which will be manual process if it is not automatically created during build time.
- This make it easier to revert to a “known good build” when things go horribly wrong or when some weird impossible to find bugs are found.

Cons:

- In the long run the tags directory
  becomes cluttered and creates
  performance issues if the number of
  tag is high in a single folder.
- Takes unnessary space in the
  repository(althought it is negligible
  in the case of svn)

Is there any other pros or cons other than the ones mentioned above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if you are talking about SVN, there is no such concept of **TAGS**. These are just another logical copies just as branches. And even if you create 'em, the old one's can be deleted anytime.

The viz-a-viz concept in Subversion is **[Revision](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.revs)**.
When you are building from SVN, each tree (trunk/branch) will have a unique revision number associated with it, and with each consecutive check-in of the code anywhere in that particular branch or trunk, the revision number of the whole tree will increment by one. **Thus, a particular branch/trunk for a particular revision number, will always be same**

I would suggest you to append the revision number of the build to the build name. This way you would know at what revision a particular branch is built. And if a comparison is required, you just compare the current build's revision of that branch to the previous build's revision. Simple!

Thus, the Tag is actually not required.

Comment: If I am right a copy operation in svn is just to associate a label with a particular revision(until the new branch is not modified). In that case having a tag for a build will not be a costly operation was my feel. However I agree with your point.

Associating the revision number to the build is a good suggestion, I  will see how it would be feasible in my environment.

Comment: Yeah, as I said... associating a label with a particular revision will not cost you until that tag/branch is modified. But, logically it won't be the best/ideal approach. Also, if you still decide to go ahead with tags, I would recommend you to use the SVN pre-commit hook to prevent tag modifications